# Youtube embedded video problem (video unavailable)

Tags: webview, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I've a got a problem when I'd like to embed a YouTube video on my expo application, when I click on the play button, I sometimes get this message :

[image: unavaible_message_from_youtube]

For example, when I posted this video on reddit, it played perfectly through their youtube embedded player.

I use this sample of code:

```
              <WebView
                useWebKit={true}
                ref={(ref) => { this.videoPlayer = ref;}}
                source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/bo_efYhYU2A?rel=0&autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=0'}}
                scrollEnabled={false}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
              />
```

I know for a fact that the video is allowed to be embedded because when it's not the case, I get a different error message which allows me to open the video on youtube :
[image: screenshot_disable_embedded]

Here is a link to test it : https://snack.expo.io/@maxgfr/youtube-embedded

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Maxime

Edit : example of url which doesn't work https://www.youtube.com/embed/8GaWM2a3FAc

Comment: Have you tried the origin to be `http` instead of `https`?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, did you figure it out?

Comment: same issue here. works with some videos and not others.

Comment: Let's check out my answer below, it's the only way that I found to solve this problem..

Comment: Looks like they did something again, it's not enough to use http://localhost:80/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve this problem :

I create a web application which loads a youtube video thanks to the video ID. My endpoint is something like that : `https://mywebsite.com/ID_VIDEO_YOUTUBE`

Then in my react native application, I just have to load the URL of my website :

```
<WebView
   useWebKit={true}
   ref={(ref) => { this.videoPlayer = ref;}}
   source={{uri: 'https://mywebsite.com/ID_VIDEO_YOUTUBE'}}
   scrollEnabled={false}
   domStorageEnabled={true}
   javaScriptEnabled={true}
/>
```

Edit : Here is the sample of code that I use in my Vue JS application

```
<template>
  <div style="position: fixed;overflow-y: hidden;overflow-x: hidden;width:100%;height:100%;">
    <iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;" :src="'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+this.$route.params.id+'?&autoplay=1&playsinline=1'" autoplay="1" playsinline="1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allow="playsinline; accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'youtube',
  head: {
    link: [{
      r: 'icon',
      h: '/static/favicon.png',
      t: 'image/png'
    }]
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide clarification of what's at your server endpoint for loading the youtube video? Is it sitting in an iframe or? I'm trying to achieve something similar but using angularJS

Comment: For AngularJS, I think that you have to create a `YoutubeVideoComponent` in which you pass the id of the youtube video that you want to load (thanks to the url params). Then, you create a route like that `{ path: 'youtube/:id', component: YoutubeVideoComponent }`. I advice you to use the sample of html code that I use or something like that in order to display a video which takes all of the width and height. Finally, in your react-native app, you just have to load the url by passing in parameter the id of the youtube video that you want to watch. I hope this is clear for you :)